# Can you create a hard disk-image of the same size as the target drive with GNU ddrescue?

Tags: disk-image, ddrescue

I'm planning on using GNU ddrescue to create a drive image of my failing 1 TB hard drive.
Can I store the image sufficiently on another 1 TB hard drive? I figure the answer would be no because the image file would contain header information which in addition to the disk-image itself should exceed the drive`s capacity (in a perfect world, but perhaps not?).

I would clone the drive, but I'm not sure how to make sure the clone isn't modified when booting up the OS (Windows or Linux).

Comment: You can compress the image or use the `--sparse` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a perfect world it should fit, but your educated guess is mostly correct.

The problem with the `--sparse` option, is that "Not all systems support this. [Only regular files can be sparse](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html)."

You can [pipe ddrescue through gzip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34003) to compress the end file on the fly. [Examples](http://www.debianadmin.com/recover-data-from-a-dead-hard-drive-using-dd.html):

```
# backup
dd if=/dev/hdx | gzip > /path/to/image.gz

# restore
gzip -dc /path/to/image.gz | dd of=/dev/hdx
```

*note that dd and ddrescue are interchangeable. They produce the same result using different techniques.*

Answer (score 0):

I would just clone the entire drive.  Assuming the drive hasn't completely been toasted I would use `dd_rescue`.

`fdisk -l` to see which drive is which and then someting like the following from a live cd:

dd_rescue /dev/sda /dev/sdb

Assuming /dev/sda is the source (bad drive) and /dev/sdb is the destination.